# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty darn new to pandas and I'm having issues with using group by. I'm trying to group by e.g., car model and car values.   I wanted it to output the average or mean price for each car model..

```
model    price
------   ----
honda     2000
Toyota    3000
```

```
file = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
file2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

file2['price'] = file2['price'].replace('#','')
file['price'] = file['price'].replace('#','')

new = pd.merge(file,file2, on=['col'])

new.drop(['cols'],inplace=True,axis=1)

**new.groupby(['car','price'].reset_index().groupby(['price']).mean(),as_index=True)**
```

I keep getting the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

I originally tried this:

```
new.groupby(['car']).groupby(['price']).mean()
```

But it was throwing a: `Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

Comment: new.groupby('car').price.mean()
?

Comment: Jeez, I just slapped my head. Haha, didn't know you could use price by itself like that..

Comment: Happy coding :-)

Comment: For the first error: ` 'list' object has no attribute 'reset_index'` I think you missed a bracket just before reset_index().. Please check!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `groupby()` with price. You can simply use

```
new.groupby('car').price
```

to access it.